# What does "snug on that perch" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Top Gun Maverick* (2022), Hangman speaks to pilot Goose:

> Hangman: Well, anyone who follows you is just gonna run out of fuel. But that's just you,
> ain't it, Rooster? You're **snug on that perch**, waiting for just the right moment...
> that never comes.

What does "snug on that perch" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Snug* means *comfortable*.

*Perch* is a place where one can sit.

*Be snug on a perch* literally means *be sitting comfortably somewhere*.

Hangman challenges Goose by telling him that his life may be too comfortable and that he may want to get out of his comfort zone.

Comment: Additionally, a perch is somewhere a bird would sit, so this is a jab at Rooster's callsign.